# Perl Stop Print if Wide Characters Error

Tags: perl

I have a simple print script

```
my $pdf_data = $agent->content;
open my $ofh, '>:raw', "test.pdf"
or die "Could not write: $!";
print {$ofh} $pdf_data;
close $ofh;
```

Sometimes I get the "Wide character warning", I know why I receive this and would like to be able to cancel the print instead of printing a corrupted fail.  Something like

```
if(wideCharWarning)
{
delete "test.pdf"
}
else{
print {$ofh} $pdf_data;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You specified you're printing bytes (:raw), but you're not.

```
$ perl -we'
   open(my $fh, ">:raw", "file") or die $!;
   for (0..258) {
      print "$_\n";
      print $fh chr($_);
   }
'
...
249
250
251
252
253
254
255
256
Wide character in print at -e line 5.
257
Wide character in print at -e line 5.
258
Wide character in print at -e line 5.
```

To "cancel the print", you simply have to check that what you print doesn't contains non-bytes.

```
die if $to_print =~ /[^\x00-\xFF]/;
```

Comment: This gets rid of the warning but I would rather (if possible) the document not print if it is not encoded properly.  I know that this means the document is not a pdf so encoding it has UTF-8 will remove the warning but the file is still corrupt.

Comment: When I change raw to encoding(utf8) I no longer receive a Wide-char warning and the output is still a corrupt pdf file.

Comment: @chrstahl89, I that up for like 2s by accident. Read again :)

Answer (score 6):

If you want to detect if your string contains wide characters, you could use a regex like this:

```
/[^\x00-\xFF]/;
```

(as ikegami noted below, my first suggestion was not ok: `/[^[:ascii:]]/;` will generate false positives)

Answer (score 1):

You could set a `__WARN__` signal handler and do anything you want to based on the warning message.

```
my $wideCharWarningsIssued = 0;
$SIG{__WARN__} = sub {
    $wideCharWarningsIssued += "@_" =~ /Wide character in .../;
    CORE::warn(@_);     # call the builtin warn as usual
};

print {$ofh} $data;
if ($wideCharWarningsIssued) {
    print "Never mind\n";
    close $ofh;
    unlink "test.pdf";
}
```